# SETSPN Error: Ldap Error(0x1 -- Operations Error): ldap_get_next_page_s

Tags: sql, powershell

I am getting an error and I don't understand why? I have googled and looked as much as I can and still do not have a clear answer. Here is what I am fast with.

```
Checking domain DC=corp,DC=local
Ldap Error(0x1 -- Operations Error): ldap_get_next_page_s
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Ldap Error(0x1 ...get_next_page_s:String) [],     RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
+ PSComputerName        : computer01.corp.local

Error occured when searching for existing SPN: 0x00000001
Checking domain DC=corp,DC=local
Ldap Error(0x1 -- Operations Error): ldap_get_next_page_s
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Ldap Error(0x1 ...get_next_page_s:String) [],     RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
+ PSComputerName        : computer01.corp.local

Error occured when searching for existing SPN: 0x00000001
```

This is the command I am running

```
$comp = "computer01.corp.local"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp -ScriptBlock {

    Invoke-Expression "SETSPN -S MSSQLSvc/$comp:1433 CORP\user.name"
    Invoke-Expression "SETSPN -S MSSQLSvc/$comp CORP\user.name"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `$comp` does not exist in your remote session, ie it is `$null` inside your `-ScriptBlock{..}` statement. Try this:

```powershell
$comp = "computer01.corp.local"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp -ScriptBlock {
    param($comp)
    Invoke-Expression "SETSPN -S MSSQLSvc/$comp:1433 CORP\user.name"
    Invoke-Expression "SETSPN -S MSSQLSvc/$comp CORP\user.name"
} -ArgumentList $comp
```

You can add `Write-Host "Working on computer:$comp"` below `param($comp)` to verify you passed variable `$comp` correctly.

Comment: Thanks! I will give that a shot and give you an update.